# MySQL vs MS SQL Server -- parallel processes doing insert/ updates

Tags: mysql, sql-server, parallel-processing, insert-update

I'm using a 3rd party ETL application (Pentaho/ Kettle/ Spoon) --- so unfortunately I'm not sure of the exact SQL query, but I can try different manual queries.

I'm just wondering why ... MySQL seems to allow multiple processes at once do an insert, but if found, update ... queries.

MS SQL does not ... it "locks" the rows when one query is doing an insert/ update ... and throws an error if another query tries to insert/ update over the same data.

I guess this makes sense ... but I'm just a bit annoyed that MySQL allows this, and MS SQL does not.

Is there any way to get around this?

I just want as fast a way as possible to insert/ update a list of 1000 records into a data table. In the past I just divided this numbers into 20 processes updating 50 records doing insert/ updates ... this worked in parallel because none of the 1000 records are duplicate ... they are only some duplicates of them already in table ... so they can be inserted/ updated in any order, so long as it happens.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: EDIT: It might also be relevant to add, only about 2-5% of the data is usually updates; the vast majority is inserts.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL use the ISAM storage engine by default which does not support transactions. SQL Server is a RDBMS and supports transactions as you've observed though you can tweak the isolation levels to do risky things like read uncommitted (very rarely a good idea).

If you want your MySQL database to have transaction support, you need to explicitly create your table with the option ENGINE=INNODB. Older versions also support ENGINE=BDB which is the Berkeley Database engine. See MySQL docs for more details on InnoDB
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I want MS SQL to copy the (apparently risky) behavior of MySQL. I want to take a list A, and then update Table B, as quickly as possible. That means having multiple, parallel processes updating Table B at once. What, might I add, is the risk ... given that there are no duplicate update keys in list A? Only one final resultant Table B could possibly occur. I want that result to occur as FAST as possible. MySQL happily complies. MS SQL doesn't because the entire table becomes locked when ONE process begins updating. So how do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by read uncommitted ... vaguely, I think ... I don't need the 'newly inserted/ updated' rows to be read or analyzed at all ... again, the list A is completely unique ... safe to say any 'new rows' or updates from list A can be ignored by "the rest" of list A. Do I need to set the lock levels from 'lock the table' to 'lock the row only' somehow?

Comment: Writes will block in MS SQL Server by default (read committed isolation level). You can change it to read uncommitted which allows similar behavior as MySQL's default. It doesn't matter if you're inserting or updating, active write rows where the transaction has not committed cannot be read by default. Your original post asks for this explicitly in the 3rd paragraph. If all you want is rapid insert, look up bulk insert in books online. Multiple insert connections work fine too though you may have other resource contention. Mixing updates/reads to the same row(s) will always block by default

Comment: Your text is pretty dense; I'm not sure I understand. To clarify just in case, I have a table 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 let's say. Those are the IDs. I have a list of insert/ updates. Say 11, 12, 13 .... 3, 6, 9. I cannot have multiple transactions doing these update/ inserts on the same table? I don't need any of the 'incoming' data rows founds read more than once. When you find a row to update, if you need to bind it, lock it, whatever, just go ahead and let the rest of the transactions read and update the rest of the table just fine. Are you saying changing to 'read uncommitted' would fix this?